# Geopandas pyproj Error: pyproj unable to set database path. _pyproj_global_context_initialize()

Tags: python, conda, geopandas, pyproj

since today i get the following error when import geopandas:
pyproj unable to set database path.
_pyproj_global_context_initialize()

andy Ideas?

Betriebssystemname:                            Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Betriebssystemversion:                         10.0.18363 Nicht zutreffend Build 18363
Betriebssystemhersteller:                      Microsoft Corporation

Python Env:
Python 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 23 2021, 07:24:41) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

conda:
conda 4.10.3

Comment: Did you activate your conda environment? That sets up environment variables that pyproj needs.

Comment: Yes I did, any other ideas? Otherwise I will setup a new env!

Comment: seems like a postgresql installation caused the error